# strange error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr when no pointers really created

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, c++14, unique-ptr

I have a class, which looks like that:

```
    template<typename T>
    using VectorPtr=std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>;

    template<typename T>
    using VectorRawPtr=std::vector<T*>;

    class ItemsSet{ // <-- Compiler say this line contans an error 0_o ?
    public:
          ItemsSet(VectorPtr<Item>& items);  

          ~ItemsSet() = default;

           VectorRawPtr<Item> GetItems();

           VectorRawPtr<Item> GetSuitableItemsForPeriod(const IPeriod &period);

           double CalculateTotal();
    private:
       VectorPtr<Item> _items;
    };
```

constructor looks like:

```
ItemsSet::ItemsSet(VectorPtr<Item> & items) {
     for(auto &itm: items){
        _items.emplace_back(std::move(itm));
     }
}
```

however this code isn't compiled and failed with error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >; _Args = {const std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >&}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:75:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> > > > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:126:15:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> > > > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >*]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:281:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >*, std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >, std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> > > > >; _ForwardIterator = std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >*; _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:322:31:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::unique_ptr<Item, std::default_delete<Item> > >]'
/cygdrive/d/code/itemSet.h:4:19:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Item; _Dp = std::default_delete<Item>]'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

Could anyone explain me what I'm doing wrong and how could I fix my problem?

Comment: Maybe the error is due to `GetItems()`? It's not returning a reference, so that would copy the vector (which would in turn try to copy all of the `unique_ptr`s within it). `GetSuitableItemsForPeriod()` might have the same problem as well. Based on the code you posted it seems like this class would work better with `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`.

Comment: @Andy I updated question and change those methods to return raw pointers, but error still there.

Comment: Returning raw pointers seems very dangerous - this is exactly the sort of situation `shared_ptr` is designed for. Only other thing I can think of is it has something to do with the initialization of `_items`. You might try moving the constructor argument directly into `_items` as suggested in the answer.

Comment: @Andy change constructor to  ItemsSet(VectorPtr<Item>&& items) and moving items inside have no any effect

Comment: That's not what I meant - I'll add an answer, easier to explain it there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that actual problem is an implicit copy constructor ither for `ItemsSet` or `Item`.  Because you using `unique_ptr`'s which can't really be copied, copy constructor can't be generated properly. Try to explicitly delete copy constructors and find the place where they used and change those place to move declaration for example, or use shared pointers.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I tryed to copy ItemSet in several places. When I change them to ItemSet& error is gone.

Comment: Surprised it matters until you actually try to copy `ItemsSet`. Which isn't shown here.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the actual code that produces the error (your line numbers don't match, and neither do the errors; you should present an actual testcase here), but we can still see the problem.

`unique_ptr`s cannot be copied (they're "unique"!), yet by copy-initialising `_items` from a whole vector of them, you're attempting to copy them all. You can't do that.

You could *move* the constructor argument into `_items` instead.

Comment: changing `ItemsSet(VectorPtr<Item> items)` to `ItemsSet(VectorPtr<Item>& items)` don't solving the problem.

Comment: @silent_coder: The problem is in your definition for that constructor (specifically, the member initialisation list). Your question is incomplete.

Comment: I added constructor code to the question, but compiler say it's fails in header file, not in implementation one. I understand that copying not allowed for unique_ptr and I'm not copying them.

Comment: making constructor arguments rvalue refference and moving them still not fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fix it or not, but you might try moving the constructor parameter directly into `_items` instead of moving each individual member into it:

```
 ItemsSet::ItemsSet(VectorPtr<Item>&& items)
 : _items(std::move(items))
 {
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this has a reason to work any better.

Comment: yes, this isn't fixing an issue =( I actaully tryed the same, conly haing this code in cpp file.

Comment: I've just encountered a similar problem. `std::move` worked as did `std::forward` but I cannot explain why.